# How did Arya survive this confrontation unscathed?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Let's have some flashback about S04E04,

When a white walker brings one of Craster's son to Night King.
So, the scene goes like this,

> [[WikiPedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oathkeeper#Plot) Later, a White Walker retrieves Craster's son. The Walker travels to the White Walkers' fortress in the Lands of Always Winter and lays the child on an altar made of ice. The leader of the White Walkers, **the Night King, approaches and places his hand on the boy, transforming him into a White Walker**.

So, they've shown that the Night King can convert living into white walkers by just touching them.

But in S08E03, it didn't seem to be the case when Arya approached the Night King to kill him.

The question is, How is Arya not transformed into a White Walker when the Night King grabs her by the neck?

Comment: There's clearly more to turning a baby into a White Walker than just touching it. Note when the Night King touched Bran, I know this is a different situation but the point stands.

Comment: yeah that's a bit of a leap to assume just because the white walker touched the baby it became one. Also, even if that was all that was required - who was to say that there didn't have to be min amount of time required or that it would work in 100% of cases? or maybe having valerian steel on you imparts immunity? there are just so many possibilities you can't deduce without more information - need someone who has read the books to give us some more information, if there is any, on how the white-walkerization process applies to someone when they are still alive.

Comment: @ycomp there isn't much else there, except to say that there may be other kinds of WW (The Night Queen), which the TV series kind of took "Coldhands" and combined him into Benjin Stark. I also suspect that much of the TV-verse WW mythology will be better explored in the 'Long Night' prequel TV series, since the synopsis includes, "origins of the white walkers", but I would love for something more to come of this, since Tormund and ghost are going North and I have a hard time believing that the whole mythological premise is just gone.

Comment: Some also theorize that Craster may relate to TNK's former human bloodline. Many assume that TKN was a Stark, and others think he was a secret Targaryen, I have a tin foil theory that he was Lann the Clever, the first alleged Lannister, but it looks like we have to wait for the prequel TV series to know for sure! Out of that cast, John Heffermen looks the most like a younger human version of him IMO.

Comment: “they've shown that the Night King can convert living into white walkers by just touching them” — we don't know that it's just by touch. He might have to wish really hard! And we don't know that he can do it to all living things. Maybe it's just babies.

Comment: yeah, I think they should've shown the whole process in season 4, right now I'm more of a convinced that this might be a plot hole, seeing what season 8 has offered so far in terms of the plot development.

Comment: Even when not converted, I think in the books the White walker shattered a steel sword by touching it. I would guess that would hurt Arya as well. But the show is a whole Other thing now.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### There was no time or intention to turn her into White Walker.

Let us look at the scene from S04E04.

A white walker brings a baby holding in his lap and puts it on an ice table (or whatever it is) for the arrival of the Night King. All were waiting for the ceremony to happen because *it is planned*. The Night King arrives at the place and changes it with his touch.

If we look at the scene from S0803 closely, it was dark. Night King was going towards Bran. Arya came running and suddenly jumps towards Night King. He senses the movement and sound and grabs Arya by her neck by reflex. So, the intention was to stop and kill her. When Arya drops the dagger, Night King looks surprised. This shows he doesn't know what would happen next. There was no time to think and turn her into a white walker by touch. There was *no planning* in this scene like S04E04. First intent is to stop and kill Arya. We *do not know* what would he do if he killed her. Even if he had so much time, it's unclear whether Night King can turn adults directly into white walkers. It's neither hinted in the show or books. When he holds Arya, we hear a cracking sound of ice. Arya was quick enough to react, drop the dagger and do the rest.

Comment: Do we even know if the Night King is able to turn full grown adults into white walkers and not just newborns?

Comment: @solalito We don't know if he can change adults into white walkers. It is not shown in the show.

Comment: @NogShine: Well, we don't know about *living* full grown adults :P About the dead we even know it works with grown dragons ;P

Comment: @NogShine Nor the books. We can suspect that to be true because then he might have tried to capture grown men alive.

Comment: @Zaibis Dead people are turned into wights, not white walkers. And it's [unclear](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79207/is-this-thing-a-wight-or-a-white-walker) exactly what Viserion became.

Comment: @Arthur: Well, in that case you got me here :)

Comment: `A wight walker brings a baby ` --> that was a `white walker`

Comment: We have exactly one single, clear observation of NK creating a new White Walker. Any explanation of how the process definitely *does* or *must* work is nothing but wild guessing. This answer is *consistent* with what we've seen, but that's nowhere near enough to be reliable or correct.

Comment: @Brad: you can correct that yourself! But never mind, I just did ;)

Comment: @rob74 I would have but it's not enough character for me to change on my own and I didn't want to muck with th rest of your answer to hit the character count

Comment: @Arthur Based on the fact that the dragon did not shatter into ice we could safely assume it was a wight, and not a white walker (flyer?)

Comment: anyone here from the book universe??  Please vouch for this.

Comment: @RJ What is your doubt? It is neither hinted in the show nor in the books that Night King can turn adults into white walkers by his touch. So, it has to be a ceremony and pre-planning even if he has to change babies into white walkers so that he can think and change through a process.

Comment: @NogShine It *doesn't* have to be that, though that would be consistent with what's shown in the TV version. There's no particular reason to think that the book and show are the same in this regard, though they may be, and neither has provided enough details to say something like this is *definitely* true. Have any of the "Inside the Episode" features discussed this at all? That might be what I'm missing. For RJ, the books include zero details about any of this, and so don't provide any clarification.

Answer (score 32):

Your assertion that "they've shown that the Night King can convert living into white walkers by just touching them" is not correct. The *only* time it happens is with **the babies taken from Craster**.

Neither the show nor the books explain how exactly this occurs but this transfer of living babies from Caster to the White Walkers seems to be the only case of the White Walkers taking living captives, moreover it is strongly implied that the transfer of babies to the White Walkers is part of a deal that Caster has struck keeping him safe. Given that there are many wildlings north of the wall that could easily be taken alive it seems likely that there is something special about this transfer that provides something the White Walkers need or otherwise why would they spare Caster in return?

The obvious conclusion is that these are the only living beings that the Night King can turn whether that is because he needs newborn, male, babies or whether there is something special about Caster himself. It also seems likely that the location where the transformation occurs is special in some way as why else would he transport the baby there? Either way, it seems likely that **Arya is alive because the Night King can only create White Walkers with a touch under special circumstances** and probably requires a baby and a special location to do so.

Comment: This - entirely this.  There may be a requirement for an altar of ice, or it may be a 3-hour ritual that only *ends* with the convert being brought to the centre of the newly empowered magic circle and "changed with a touch".  There are dozens of potential prerequisites and requirements that could be missing.  After all, if a touch was all it took then surely the Night King would have trained himself as a master of unarmed combat, and just converted his enemies mid-battle?

Comment: @Chronocidal I never realized that I wanted this martial arts movie...

Comment: @Adonalsium I propose we name the protagonist "Frederick".  The film will be called "Fist of the Morph Star".  Tagline?  ["Watatatatata....  You are already Fred"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fist_of_the_North_Star)

Answer (score 4):

I think a good question is why are there so few White Walkers? In the scene where the Night King turns the baby into a White Walker we only see 12 or 13 in the background. The Night King has been around since the age of the First Men, something like 8,000 years, and there are only 13 White Walkers? Why wouldn't he make an entire army of White Walkers? That would be a far more effective force than the wights are.

The limited number of White Walkers suggests one or more of the following:

1. It isn't simple to do (and therefore can't be done quickly)
2. Only certain types of humans can become White Walkers (i.e., males, babies, red heads, etc.)
3. The Night King is highly selective based on some other criteria

I can't remember seeing a female White Walkers, so that alone suggests that Arya could not become one.

Comment: As for the female while walker, we can see the the free folk lady turns into a white walking at the hard home episode while john and others flee using boats.

Comment: @BkSantiago You're mixing up wights (basically zombies, light blue eyes, can be any dead animal, no special powers, vulnerable to fire) with white walkers (called "others" in the books; blue skin despite the name, white hair, darker blue eyes with a pattern, ice swords that crack regular metals, can freeze nearby water and put out nearby fires). Many people do mix these up... I really wish they hadn't chosen two such similar names and appearances.